# Prestashop block cart and cart controller

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, prestashop

We have followed this guys tutorial on changing the prestashop add to cart animation

http://nemops.com/better-prestashop-add-to-cart/

However, now the problem we face is if someone adds a quantity to the cart that is greater than the quantity we have in stock. The popup box still shows and we still get the default prestashop error "There isn't enough product in stock".

We thought that in the ajax-cart.js where we added the new code that we could run and if statement against the quantity added and the quantity in stock. If the quantity added is greater than what we have in stock then do not display the box. We are stuck on how to check the quantity added vs the quantity in stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the quantity you have

```
var  availableQuantity = {$product->quantity};
```

and then dissable add to cart button if available quantity is less then added to cart value

Comment: In which file does this belong? I tried blockcart.tpl, but it didn't work.

Comment: you should write it by yourself to templates you need